# Token Metadata in Tokbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, opentok, tokbox

I am trying to create a video chatting service that has multiple user types.   Based on these "roles" a user may simply be an observer, or an actual participant in a call.  I know via the Tokbox Api (https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/create-token/node/index.html) that you can attach metadata to tokens, but I can't for the life of me decipher how to access them on the client side. See my token creation code:

```js
app.get("/gettoken", function(req, res) {
   var sessionId = req.query.sessionid;
   var userrole = req.query.role;
   var tokenOptions = {};
   tokenOptions.role = "publisher";
   tokenOptions.data = "role="+userrole;
   var token = opentok.generateToken(sessionId, tokenOptions);
   res.send({token: token});
})
```

And my session subscription code that is called when a new subscriber joins the stream:

```js
session.on({
   streamCreated: function(event) {
      session.subscribe(event.stream, 'theirCamDiv', {
         insertMode: 'append'
       });
       console.log(??Subscriber Metadata??);
   }
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can access your token metadata from `event.stream.connection.data` property, so in your case

```
session.on({
  streamCreated: function(event) {
     session.subscribe(event.stream, 'theirCamDiv', {
        insertMode: 'append'
      });
      console.log(event.stream.connection.data);
  }
});
```